# Изменение настроек Gradle в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

При создании нового проекта в Gradle устанавливается значение кучи 2048 mb. Такой объем не всегда доступен и это вызывает ошибку.

Как можно изменить значения, которые задаются новому проекту по умолчанию, что бы не приходилось менять конфигурацию каждого проекта вручную?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете установить общие настройки gradle, которые будут применены для всех проектов, в которых специально не указано иное.

Следуете по пути: `C:\Users\<User Name>\.gradle`

открываете в каком-нибудь Блокноте файл *gradle.properties*

и прописываете там требуемые параметры по умолчанию, например:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

где:
*Xms* - изначально выделяемая модулю gradle память
*Xmx* - максимально доступная этому модулю память.

так же в конфиге присутствуют некоторые оптимизации для ускорения работы gradle

Так же вы можете править этот же файл прямо из *Android Studio* дважды кликнув по файлу *gradle.properties (Global Properties)* в окне списка файлов проекта.

[image: srennshot]

Comment: Я создал такой файл, при создании проекта он отображается в списке файлов(global properties). Но локальные настройки (gradle.properties(Project properties)) не меняются, то есть размер кучи для новых проектов остается 2048mb. Какой то другой файл может использоваться при создании проекта?

Comment: Локальные настройки в файле `gradle.properties(Project properties)` и не должны меняться при этом. Если в локальных не указано иное, будут применены глобальные. Как вы определяете размер выделяемой памяти?