# Проблемы с рекламой Appodeal

Tags: java, android

Поставил рекламу Appodeal,везде следовал документации.После компиляции выдало ошибку

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Еще не понимаю почему приложение стало очень долго компилироваться. Все начало после того, как поставил рекламу

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html попробуйте. Подключили библиотеки, вот и стало долго компилироваться.

Comment: А вы не можете объяснить почему такая медлительная компиляция приложение, после того как поставил рекламу Appodeal ?

Comment: Gradle сам по себе не особо шустрый, а тут дополнительная нагрузка. Можете попробовать советы по ускорению, к примеру: https://toster.ru/q/42494 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478445/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA-gradle-%D0%B2-android-studio